# git diff specific file my-branch to master

Tags: git, diff

- what is the simplest way to see a *specific* file diff from my branch to master?
- everything on my branch is pushed
- I prefer to use *branch names* rather than commits' hashes (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175356/git-diff-compare-specific-versions-of-specific-file))
- I want a *single file diff* rather than a full blown diff of branches (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808892/git-diff-between-current-branch-and-master-but-not-including-unmerged-master-com))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+one+file

Comment: `git diff master -- path/to/myfile.py` or `git diff master HEAD -- path/to/myfile.py`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
$ git diff origin/master:path/to/myfile.py path/to/myfile.py
```

Note that order *does* matter (master branch should come first)

Comment: or even shorter: `git diff master -- path/to/myfile.py`

Comment: Assuming you are on "my-branch", yes.